# RegEx - Match all unquoted strings in brackets except if they are all capital-letters

Tags: php, regex, search, replace

In PHP 7.2, the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.deprecated.php) says:

> Unquoted strings that are non-existent global constants are taken to
>   be strings of themselves. This behaviour used to emit an **E_NOTICE**, but
>   will now emit an **E_WARNING**. In the next major version of PHP, an Error
>   exception will be thrown instead.

Also, code like this `$list[products_name]`, will now produce this warning:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant products_name - assumed 'products_name'
>   (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in %s on line %d

I have now switched to PHP 7.2 and got such code that I would like to search and replace, by matching all unqoted strings inside brackets and add single-quotes to them (eg. `$list[products_name]` will become `$list['products_name']`), except for strings that are all capital. The reason I want to skip those specifically is because many times they are indeed constants and I shouldn't put them inside quotes.
I am new to regex and tried several options. So far, I have come up with this regex:

```
\$\w+\[([a-zA-Z_]+[\w]+)\]
```

It works well for most purposes I need it, except it still captures all capital strings in code blocks like this:

```
$options[$list[_option_id]][]=array($list[_value],$list[_value_id]);
      $option_names[$list[_option_id1]]=$list[_option];
      $product_name=$list[products_name];
$product_name=$list[0];
$product_name=$list[DONTCAPTUREME];
$product_name=$list[CapTureMe];
$product_name=$list[CapTurEME];
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/I91TNn/2/)

How can I modify it to not match only examples like `DONTCAPTUREME`?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after the first `\[`, use negative lookahead for all-caps followed by `\]`:

```
\$\w+\[(?![A-Z]+\])([a-zA-Z_]+[\w]+)\]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/I91TNn/3

Comment: I know it is not part of the original question, but how can I make it also skip `DONT_CAPTURE_ME`. I have tried with  `\$\w+\[(?![A-Z_]+\])([a-zA-Z_]+[\w]+)\]` but that also skips many other ones that I do need to capture. So I basically need to skip all caps and all caps+_ only.

Comment: Just add `_` to the character set in the negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/I91TNn/4 Another option is positive lookahead for anything but a `\]`, repeated, followed by a lowercase `\$\w+\[(?=[^\]]*[a-z])([a-zA-Z_]+[\w]+)\]`

Comment: `also skips many other ones` Can you replicate the problem on regex101? I'm curious

Comment: I can't, works fine on regex101. I am using grepWin, which usually works great with these, but for some reason - not this time. It does pick lines like `$actionKey = $get[AM_ACTION_GET_VARIABLE];` Any other way to do this regex?

Comment: The issue was that the program was set to search case insensitive by default. Changing this to case sensitive regex search fix that problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Finally the solution that worked best for me (using [grepWin](https://github.com/stefankueng/grepWin/releases)) is:

**Search** (case sensitive **must be enabled**):

```
(").*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\$\w+\]?\[(?!\w*\(|\w*:)(?=[^\]]*[a-z])(\K[a-zA-Z_]+[\w]+)
```

**Replace with:**

```
'\2'
```

**Always backup your files before such operation.**

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tsf5HG/1/)

[Screenshot Here](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xuX3altlcR4/W2mK6IyEl6I/AAAAAAAAKlA/KwpqEwLRWRkcVAbhiNLK-iC4a4q8DUb3wCHMYCw/s0/grepWin_2018-08-07_19-04-55.png)